# RMI - remote object , rmiregistry

Tags: rmi

Is it true that every remote object must be registered in rmiregistry ? Can we get one object from rmiregistry , call method on it and as a result get a reference ( not a serialized copy ) to another remote object , which isn't registred in rmiregistry ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it true that every remote object must be registered in rmiregistry?

No.

> Can we get one object from rmiregistry , call method on it and as a result get a reference ( not a serialized copy ) to another remote object , which isn't registred in rmiregistry ?

Yes.

Remote methods can return remote objects. The Registry is only a bootstrap mechanism to get you started, i.e. to provide you with an initial stub. After that you can do anything you like.

Comment: Thank you for response, but I didn't understand this "Remote methods can return remote objects" . How to make a remote object without registration it in rmiregistry ? If we use export method to make it remote, it's automatically registered in rmiregistry

Comment: No it isn't. Exporting just exports the remote object. It is `bind()/rebind()` that registers the object in the Registry. To return a remote object you don't need anything more than a return statement, providing an exported remote object as the value. If the object extends `UnicastRemoteObject` it can be as simple as `return new MyRemoteObject();`.

Comment: Right, I understand it now. Thank you